# Enable Multi Page Sub report in Acumatica Report Designer

Tags: acumatica

When a sub report spans on multiple pages, the main report looses all control of pagination. This results in the report cutting off at the end of the first page when in PDF mode.
Example:
Our invoices use multiple sub reports to get shipment and sales order details.
When the invoice gets emailed out by the system to customers, the data beyond the first page is missing.

Question: How can we get a sub report to display all the data it should?

Per Acumatica support we tried toggling "keep together" and adding a page break after, but it did not work.

Note that when printing the report in html display mode, the data does display correctly. It also displays correctly if we save as PDF via the browser print screen.
See images for illustration:
[image: HTML view - full invoice]

[image: pdf view - missing data]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution that worked and explanation (Based on Acumatica support response):
When a subreport is printed as a part of the main report, and the information in the subreport takes more than one page, the system does not break the page flow and prints all information in one long grid. When the report is exported to PDF, the information from the subreport is incomplete. The following steps will allow you to insert a page break in the subreport:

1. Place the Subreport is a separate GroupHeaderSection
2. Allow some space between the Subreport control and the section borders

[Allow Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSZlc.jpg)

3. In the GroupHeaderSection properties tab, set the Keep Together parameter to False

[GroupHeader Params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvTbY.jpg)

4. Set the PageBreak parameter to After, so that the Subreport Page Footer is printed as the last line of the Subreport

[PageBreak result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgwEF.jpg)

The next section of the main report will start on the following page.>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following:
go to the master report rpx file and find the section where you put the master report.
And then find the KeepTogether attribute under Behavior, and set it to be false.

Please let me know if it works.